# How to send an array of Flex checkboxes to a mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, checkbox, repeater

I am using FB for PHP 4.5, ZendAMF, and I read that I do not need to use HTTPService for what I want to do.

Table structure:

```
people: {pID, pName}
departments: {deptID, deptName}
people_departments: {pID, deptName}
```

I have a slightly complex flex script, People.mxml. In the PersonAdd state, I have a form which will be used to send data to the mysql server. In that form , I have a repeater that will create a checkbox for every department in my database. When I click the Add button, I want to insert data into the `people` and `people_departments` tables.

Repeater code:

```
<mx:HBox>
  <mx:Repeater id="checkBoxRepeater"
               dataProvider="{getDepartmentsResult.lastResult}">
    <s:CheckBox id="deptCB"
                label="{checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.deptName}"/>
  </mx:Repeater>
</mx:HBox>
```

In my peopleService.php file, I will have the function `createPerson(People $item,$deptArray)` and inside that function, I will execute two SQL queries. One query will insert data into the People table and the other one will insert data into people_departments, with `people_departments.pID` = ID of newly inserted person.

As you can see, in the Repeater code above, the checkbox as the attribute label. However, when I send the dept_Array (of type ArrayCollection) to the server, the former needs to contain deptIDs. How can I do so?

This is how I create the dept_Array in People.mxml to send to the server:

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var dept_array:Array=[];
 var idx:int;
 var getDepts_array:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection;
 getDepts_array=getDepartmentsResult.lastResult as ArrayCollection;
 var len:int=getDepts_array.length;
 for (idx=0; idx < len; idx++)
 {
  if (deptCB[idx].selected)
  {
   dept_array.push(deptCB[idx].label); //here I need to be able to push the ID of selected department.
  }
 }
}
```

[Edit] I am using an s:Checkbox and I do not have the data property. mx:Checkbox does but I cannot use the mx:Checkbox component in my project.

I would appreciate any help. Also, is there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the attribute `automationName` to send the ID related to the itemName displayed as the checkbox label.

Note that the `data` attribute does not exist for the spark checkbox. If you use the mx:Checkbox, you have data, and you can use it to send the ID linked to your item in question.

```
<mx:Tile id="myTile">
  <mx:Repeater id="checkBoxRepeater"
               dataProvider="{getItemsResult.lastResult}"
               startingIndex="0">
  <s:CheckBox label="{checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.myItemName}"
              id="checkbox"
              automationName="{String(checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.myItemID)}"
              change="checkbox_changeHandler(event,event.currentTarget.repeaterIndex)"/>^
  </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Tile>
```

I know that this may not be the best solution, but I am apparently the first person to do this commonplace task, and this worked for me.

And then, the send the array of the IDs of the selected checkboxes, I use the following code, defined in my submitBtn_clickHandler function:

```
var items_array:Array=[];
var idx:int;
var getitems_array:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection;
getitems_array=getItemsResult.lastResult as ArrayCollection;
var len:int=getitems_array.length;
for (idx=0; idx < len; idx++)
  {
    var element:CheckBox=myTile.getElementAt(idx) as CheckBox;
    if (element.selected)
    {
      items_array.push(element.automationName);
    }
  }
```

I then pass `items_array` as an additional parameter to my ItemService.createItem function.

Answer (score 0):

try to bind the selected property with your getDepartmentsResult to save the selected state :

```
<mx:HBox>
  <mx:Repeater id="checkBoxRepeater"
               dataProvider="{getDepartmentsResult.lastResult}">
    <s:CheckBox id="deptCB"
                label="{checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.deptName}" selected={checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.deptSelected}/>
  </mx:Repeater>
</mx:HBox>
```

After that iterate on your collection to get the selected department:

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var dept_array:Array=[];
 var idx:int;
 var getDepts_array:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection;
 getDepts_array=getDepartmentsResult.lastResult as ArrayCollection;
 var len:int=getDepts_array.length;
 for each (var dept:Object in getDepts_array) {
    // ...
}
  if (dept.selected)
  {
   dept_array.push(dept.label); //here I need to be able to push the ID of selected department.
  }
```

}
}

Comment: That would not work, because first, I do not have the `deptSelected` field in my table, and secondly, `selected` is a boolean attribute.

What I eventually did is fire up the documentation as usual, and scrutinize the whole list. I found one attribute that could take a string, and I _cheated_ a bit and used the `automationName` property to do what I wanted to do.

Comment: `<s:CheckBox label="{checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.myItemName}"
id="checkbox"
automationName="{String(checkBoxRepeater.currentItem.myItemID)}"
change="checkbox_changeHandler(event,event.currentTarget.repeaterIndex)"/>`